# Is -(E,E) greater or equal to 2 for a minimal resolution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, surfaces

I'm quite confused by the terminology *minimal resolution* and *minimal model*.

Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a minimal resolution of singularities, where $Y$ is a normal surface.

Let $E$ be an exceptional component.

Do we have that the intersection number $-(E,E)\geq 2$?

By Castelnuovo' criterion,  this has to do with the minimality of $X$. I know one could blow down all the curves such that $-(E,E) = 1$ to obtain a minimal model, but if $Y$ is already regular and contains such curves, then so will $X$ right?

So *minimal resolution* and *minimal model* aren't always the same, right?

Comment: You're partially right. Smooth rational components of the exceptional
divisor must have $E^2\le -2$, but other components could
have $E^2=-1$. Furthermore, the notion of minimal resolution is
relative to $Y$, so it is not necessarily a minimal model.

Comment: I see! Actually in the article I'm reading the surface has only rational singularities. that's why they get to use that $E^2 \leq -2$ because the components of the exceptional divisor are all rational. Thank you for clearing this up for me.